# Struts 2 dynamic variables

Tags: struts2, ognl, dynamic-variables

I'm trying to create a dynamic variable in Struts2 using set tag

```xml
<s:set var="myNum" value="numConst" />
<s:set var="number" value="%{getText('@xxx.CommonConstant@'+#myNum)}" />
```

`numConst` will return a dynamic value that retrieved from database. For example, if the value is NINE then number should be `@xxx.CommonConstant@NINE`

I have set the value in my java class so that `@xxx.CommonConstant@NINE` will return `9`.

So far, the value can be displayed with no problem in text tag if I use

```xml
<s:text name="%{getText(#number)}" />
```

It will return `9` but it displayed incorrectly when I tried using property tag

```xml
<s:property value="%{getText(#number)}" /> 
<s:property value="%{#number}" />
<s:property value="#number" />
<s:property value="%{getText('%{getText(#number)}')}" />
```

Which all of the above examples will give me the value as `@xxx.CommonConstant@NINE`. The reason I try to get the value from property tag is because I want to copy the correct way on how to display the value so I can use them in if tag like below examples:

```xml
<s:if test="#number == 9">
   do something
</s:if>
```

or

```xml
<s:if test="%{getText(#number)} == 9">
   do something
</s:if>
```

**CommonConstant:**

```
package xxx;

public abstract class CommonConstant {
    public static final int NINE = 9;
    public static final int NINEONE = 91;
    public static final double ADMIN_PGM = 1.4;
    // ... omitted ... 
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: And what is `CommonConstant`? Is it `enum`? Could you show the code.

Comment: `getText` method is for getting localized text. Why are you using it like that?

Comment: `package xxx;

public abstract class CommonConstant {

 public static final int NINE = 9;
 public static final int NINEONE = 91;
 public static final double ADMIN_PGM = 1.4;

 ... omitted ...
}`

Comment: yeah @AleksandrM I guess because I get used to use localization until I tried it out.. but <s:text name="%{#number}" /> also will give me the expected value but not with <s:property value="%{#number}" />

Comment: Yuck. If you actually need this then change how it works on the server side; make a real map. Also more testable that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like a workaround but you can use `attr` to evaluate string.

```
<s:set var="myNum" value="numConst" />
<s:set var="number" value="'@xxx.CommonConstant@'+#myNum" />

<s:property value="#attr[#number]"/>

<s:if test="#attr[#number] == 9">
  do something
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use parenthesesized expression to evaluate result of the expression.

```xml
<s:if test="#number(0) == 9">
  <s:property value="%{#number(0)}" />
</s:if>
```

Look at the [Expression Evaluation](https://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Expression_Evaluation) of the OGNL language guide.