# Struts 2.0 - dynamically append the s:property value

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have some objects of same type in action class..

E.g.:

```
LivingThings fish = new LivingThings("FISH");    
LivingThings dog = new LivingThings("DOG");    
LivingThings lion = new LivingThings("LION");
```

The contents of each objects will be different.

Also in the same action class I have a list with values as the name of the objects
i.e.

```
ArrayList<String> animalsList = new ArrayList<String>();    
animalsList.add("fish");
animalsList.add("dog");
animalsList.add("lion");
```

=====

Now in the jsp page, I need dynamically get the object contents using the `animalsList` contents. i.e.

```
<s:iterator value="animalsList" id="eachAnimal">
    <s:property value="#eachAnimal.lifespan" />
</s:iterator>
```

Here all I am trying to do is, instead of directly giving the code like

```
<s:property value="fish.lifespan" />
<s:property value="dog.lifespan" />
<s:property value="lion.lifespan" />
```

Somehow, I need append the object name from the `animalsList` list. Is it possible in struts 2.0. I am little bit confused with OGNL concept.
I tried these scenarios:

```
<s:iterator value="animalsList" id="eachAnimal">
    <s:property value="#eachAnimal.lifespan" />
    <s:property value="%{eachAnimal}.lifespan" />
    <s:property value="%{#eachAnimal}.lifespan" />
</s:iterator>
```

Can someone give me suggestions?

Comment: Using 2.0, IIRC `%{#eachAnimal.lifespan}` should work; are you saying it doesn't? I'd recommend not using such an old version of S2, though.

Comment: Why cannot you store `LivingThings` in your list instead of strings? Anyway you can use OGNL evaluation like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16712395/1700321.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, its not working.. i am using the latest jar files.. am using struts2-core-2.3.14.jar....

Comment: @AleksandrM i could hv used LivingThings as list, but my scenario is this.. thts why..

but when i tried with <s:property value="#attr[#eachAnimal].lifespan" /> its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is not the best way to handle such case, but what you asking for could be done something like so:

```
<s:iterator value="animalsList" id="eachAnimal">
  <s:property value="#attr[#eachAnimal].lifespan" />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Aleksandr, its working now... :-), but why did you mention, its not the best way.. any drawback or performance issues.. anything..

Comment: @abyin007: It may be not the best way, because I don't know what you are trying to achieve. BTW accept/upvote answers that helped you.