# struts2 get property with dynamic value in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a problem with struts property, pl check my sample code.

in struts action class i have a property that is `name2`,

**SampleAction.java**

```
public class SampleAction extends ActionSupport
{
private String name2;// setter and getter is also there

}
```

if i use like below i ll get the value

```
<s:property value="name2"/>
```

I wan to get the `name2` value in jsp in dynamic way,

but here i need pass the value `2` in dynamic way some thing like below..

```
<s:set name="nameNumber" value="2" />
<s:property value="name%{#nameNumber}"/>
```

How can i achieve that.

Thanks in Advance,
Prabhakar Manthena

Comment: I think it should be "name%{nameNumber}" (without #) but not sure.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16712395/1700321.

Comment: @ThrashBean I already tried.. no use :(

Comment: It doesn't really work like this; you're asking for double-evaluation.