# Servlet property with dynamic name

Tags: jsp, dojo, widget

I have created a custom Dojo 1.9 widget that is intended to be a one-size-fits-all combobox where I can insert any dojo widget with a drop-down declaratively, so in my jsp page.

This is an example of a dojo Combobox that I'm hoping to replace with this Widget:

```xml
<div data-dojo-type="dojo/store/Memory"                                                
    data-dojo-id="machineNameStore"                                                    
    data-dojo-props="<s:property value='%{getNameJsonString()}'/>"></div>              
<s:set name="MachineName" value="machineSearchView.name"                               
    scope="request"></s:set>                                                           
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox"                                              
    data-dojo-props="store:machineNameStore, searchAttr:'name', value:'${MachineName}'"
    name="machineSearchView.name" id="machineSearchView.name" />
```

This is the html code of my widget:

```xml
<div class="${baseClass}">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojo/store/Memory" data-dojo-attach-point="memoryNode"
    data-dojo-id="${dataStoreId}"
    data-dojo-props="${dataSourceData}"></div>
    <s:set name="${fieldName}" value="${searchViewFieldName}" scope="request"> <s:set>
    <div data-dojo-type="${dropDownType}" data-dojo-attach-point="dropDownNode"
    data-dojo-props="store:${dataStoreId}, searchAttr:'${searchAttrName}', value: '${fieldName}'"
    name="${searchViewFieldName}" id="${searchViewFieldName}" ></div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript code of my widget:

```xml
/**
 * Javascript for ExpandableSearchComponent
 */
define([ "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
        "dojo/text!./templates/ExpandableSearchComponent.html",
        "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin", "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dijit/form/Select",
        "dijit/form/FilteringSelect"

], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template,
        _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Memory) {

    return declare([ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
        templateString : template,
        fieldName : "",
        dataSourceData : "",
        dropDownType : "",
        searchAttrName : "",
        searchViewFieldName : ""
    });

});
```

And this is how the widget is called in the page:

```xml
<div data-dojo-type="js/widgets/ExpandableSearchComponent"                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    data-dojo-id="operatingSystemStore"                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    data-dojo-props="dataSourceData: '<s:property value='%{getNameJsonString()}'/>',
    fieldName:'machineName' , dataStoreId: 'machineNameDataStore',
    dropDownType: 'dijit/form/ComboBox', searchAttrName: 'name', 
    searchViewFieldName: 'machineSearchView.name'"></div>
```

This works for about 90% and makes me hopeful that I can make it work completely. My big bug right now before I start expanding on this so it has the appearance of what I want it to be is a problem with the dropdown value element.

As you can see, I have a request-scope servlet property which takes the name of the machine I'm searching for and passes it into the value of my combobox. I need to be able to add multiple instances of my Dojo Widget to my page, so I need to be able to make the name of this servlet property a variable. However, in my Dojo combobox value, I need to use this property I created as the value of the dojo property. So I essentially want to say "insert a JSP property into this page with name X", where X = `${fieldName}` generated by Dojo. However, this means generating a servlet AFTER it has already been sent to the page and processed by Dojo.

I've checked other answers, like [struts2 get property with dynamic value in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498035/struts2-get-property-with-dynamic-value-in-jsp) and the therein linked questions, but the problem is that those all use either `<s:text>` or `<s:property>`, but Dojo can't parse a widget where those are in the `data-dojo-props` tag. And if I just try to surround `${fieldName}` with another `${}`, that doesn't get parsed properly.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

---

Clarification as requested in comments:

1. Desired behaviour: I want to use Dojo to generate the first HTML code snippet when I write the 4th snippet.
2. Reproducible problem: I get the right snippet mostly, but when ${fieldName} is parsed by Dojo, it turns into machineName, which is what I want in the s:set, but in the Combobox, when entering it as the value, it's written down as a string literal machineName. I want to adjust my 2nd and 3rd snippet so instead of `value: 'machineName'`, it reads `value:'${machineName}'` Like in the first snippet so it retrieves the request-scope parameter set in the s:set.
   The essence is that the current value of machineSearchView.name in my struts2 action should be preselected in the combobox. That's what I want to achieve. However, I also want to use multiple instances of this element in the same JSP page, which I think means I can't have them all have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing, I have found a solution to my problem. In effect, I have split off the servlet translation logic to the page itself, instead of trying to do so in Dojo.

html:

```
<div class="${baseClass}">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojo/store/Memory" data-dojo-attach-point="memoryNode"
    data-dojo-id="${dataStoreId}"
    data-dojo-props="${dataSourceData}"></div>    
    <div data-dojo-type="${dropDownType}" data-dojo-attach-point="dropDownNode"
    data-dojo-props="store:${dataStoreSearchProp}, name: '${searchViewFieldName}', value: '${valueSearchProp}'" name="${searchViewFieldName}" id="${searchViewFieldName}" ></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
/**
 * Javascript for ExpandableSearchComponent
 */
define([ "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
        "dojo/text!./templates/ExpandableSearchComponent.html",
        "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dijit/form/Select",
        "dijit/form/FilteringSelect"

], function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template,
        _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, Memory, parser) {

    return declare([ _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
        templateString : template,
        fieldName : "",
        searchProps : "",
        dataSourceData : "",
        dataStoreSearchProp: "",
        NameSearchProp:"",
        valueSearchProp:"",
        dropDownType : "",
        searchViewFieldName : "",
    });

});
```

How it's used:

```
<s:set var='machineName' value='machineSearchView.name'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    scope='request'>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
</s:set>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
<div data-dojo-type="js/widgets/ExpandableSearchComponent"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    data-dojo-id="operatingSystemStore"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    data-dojo-props="dataSourceData: '<s:property value='%{getNameJsonString()}'/>', dataStoreSearchProp: 'machineNameDataStore', valueSearchProp: '${machineName}', dataStoreId:'machineNameDataStore', dropDownType: 'dijit/form/ComboBox', searchViewFieldName: 'machineSearchView.name'"></div>
</td>
```

However, because of business miscommunication, this is not the solution I will be going with in the end.