# Struts2: Evaluate string literal for property value

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, dynamic-variables, struts-tags

I am trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712395/struts-2-dynamic-variables) but the answers don't fix my problem. I'm using Struts2 version 2.3.28.1.

I'm trying to access data in the session using a `<s:property>` tag and a dynamic value string literal.

If I do:

```
<s:property value="#session.data_1"></s:property>
```

Then the correct data is displayed. Now when I try the following:

```
<s:set var="part1" value="#variable.code"></s:set>
<s:set var="part2" value="'#session.data_'+#part1"></s:set>

<s:property value="part2"></s:property> 
<s:property value="%{part2}"></s:property> 
<s:property value="%{#part2}"></s:property>
<s:property value="#attr[#part2]" default="Not working"></s:property>
<s:property value="(#part2)" default="Not working"></s:property>
<s:property value="%{(#part2)}" default="Not working"></s:property>
```

Which displays :

```
#session.data_1
#session.data_1
#session.data_1
Not working
#session.data_1
#session.data_1
```

(Yes I kinda tried every possible combination that I could think of even if they don't make sense...)

How can I make the `<s:property>` tag evaluate `#part2` instead of interpreting as a string literal? In my understanding `%{}` should have done the trick but nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve value from the session and going through the `#attr` it isn't going to work.

There is simpler way. Use the `#session` keyword directly.

```
<s:property value="#session['data_' + #variable.code]" />
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was hitting my head on the desk with that one haha