# Struts 2. s:property. How to get the value of a variable whose name is passed as a parameter to the jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tags

I have a class `Message.java` with two variables of same type `Location.java` called `origin` and `destination`

**Message.java**

```
public class Message{

    private Location origin;
    private Location destination;

//Getters and setters correctly defined   
}
```

**Location.java**

```
public class Location{

private String address;    
}
```

**MessageAction.java**

```
 public class MessageAction {

        private Message message;
       //Getters and setters correctly defined   
    }
```

I want to reuse code, so I have created a common JSP and pass the name of these variables by parameter. (Of course, the code is more complex, this is only a basic example, so it really helps me to reuse code)

**message.jsp**

```jsp
<s:push value="message">
    <s:include value="/jsp/location.jsp">
        <s:param name="variableName" value="'origin'" />
    </s:include>
    <s:include value="/jsp/location.jsp">
        <s:param name="variableName" value="'destination'" />
    </s:include>
</push>
```

Here comes the problem, I don't know how to show the value of `%{variableName}.address`. I have tried several combinations and googled a while but I haven't found anything.

**location.jsp**

```jsp
<s:set name="variableName">${param.variableName}</s:set>
<s:property value="%{%{variableName}.address}" />
```

If I write directly the names of the variables, I receive their value correctly, so the Action is setting them correctly.

```jsp
<s:property value="origin.address" />
<s:property value="destination.address" />
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16712395/1700321.

Answer (score 0):

This is just wrong OGNL expression

```
%{%{variableName}.address}
```

if you want to reuse JSP as templete then you should use valid OGNL expression. Nevertheless passing parameter name is enormous since you will have complex OGNL to return the value of this parameter name.

You should also know that

> Parameters are passed as request parameters, so use the `${param.ParamName}` notation to access them. Do not use the `property` tag to access parameters in included files.